# Accepting Android volume rocker input across a range of states

Tags: android, lockscreen, wakelock, android-wake-lock, keyguard

I have an app that will generally be the sole app for which a device (Android 4.2 and up) is used. It needs to be able to accept input from the volume rockers in the following scenarios:

1. app is in foreground
2. app is in background
3. lock screen or keyguard has been engaged
4. screen has been switched off (ie idle mode).

(1) is easily solved by listening for KeyDown events in the Activity

(2) can be partially solved by listening for `android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION` (yes I know it's not public API, but it works all devices I have managed to test it on and I can't find an alternate). But on my Nexus 5 (Android 6.0), on first press of the rocker it displays the volume dialog for a short duration and requires a second press to pass the rocker event to my app. I haven't managed to pin down for which version of Android this started occurring, but I'd like to work how how to ensure the *first* event is passed to my app for all Android versions.

(3) can be mitigated by using WindowManager `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD` and `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` to avoid lock screen and keyguard

(4) can be partially mitigated by using WindowManager `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` to ignore display timeouts when app is in foreground. But unfortunately it is a common event for the user to accidentally manually power the screen off, and even using a `WAKE_LOCK` doesn't allow the volume rocker events to be received via  `android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION` when the screen is idle.

So the questions are:

1. How do I ensure that the first press of the volume rocker is passed to my app, rather than being captured and consumed by the volume dialog?
2. How can I receive volume rocker events when the screen is idle?